# PHP class constant for each string exist in class, Is good or bad idea?

Tags: php, constants

I am creating const for every sting exist in file so its good or bad idea?
later when something is break than tracing will easy or hard?

```
class GoogleSpreadsheet {
    const WHITE_SPACE=' ';
    const TIME_LIMIT=0;
    const REDIRECT_PATH='test.php';
    const FLAG_ONE=1;
    const SET_MEMORY_LIMIT_VALUE=-1;
    const FIRST_ELEMENT_INDEX=0;
    const SUBTRACT_CONDITION='-1';
    const MAX_NEW_WORKSHEET_ROWS=10;
    const ALPHANUMERIC_CHARACTERS_REGEX='/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\.]+/';
    const FORWARD_SLASH_SEPARATORS="/";
    const URL_SELF_FIELD='self';
    const SET_MEMORY_LIMIT='memory_limit';

    function __construct() {
        set_time_limit(self::TIME_LIMIT);
        ini_set(self::SET_MEMORY_LIMIT, self::SET_MEMORY_LIMIT_VALUE);
        extract(func_get_arg(self::FIRST_ELEMENT_INDEX));
        $this->spreadsheetKey=(isset($spreadsheetKey))?$spreadsheetKey:$this->spreadsheetKey;
        $this->worksheetId=(isset($worksheetId))?$worksheetId:$this->worksheetId;
        if (isset($googleUsername)&&isset($googlePassword)) {
            $this->loginGoogle($googleUsername, $googlePassword);
        }
    }
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: The question is not clear. But the class by itself looks weird: you declare constants for things that are constant by their nature. Like `''` and `1` are always an empty string and a number one correspondingly.

Comment: @zerkms
ok understand your point but if i create const for each and every sting exist in class ? it will create problem later?

Comment: every programming decision must be caused by something. What reason do you follow and how adding number of constants for already constant things is supposed to make code better?

Comment: @zerkms yes thats why I used const but my quotation is : to follow constant for each string (may be 100 or more for some files). it will create any issue letter.

Comment: Well, the problem, as I see it, has more to do with setting INI options and time limits in a constructor. What happens if the class is instantiated more than once? Since these things apply globally they should be set in the global scope.

Comment: @Raidon: `1` is a constant already. This literal is immutable and always represents a number `one`. I seriously don't see how it's better than `self::FLAG_ONE`

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I just need to know if define more const in file for   string values than its good or bad? any problem letter, i am new in php

Comment: You don't need to wait for a problem later - you already have a problem. For the 2 lines code you have 20.

Comment: @zerkms this is just an example, I will redeclare php predefine constant as you stated for empty string and flag one but while code tracing code/issue const is better than static string ?

Comment: It's not better. `1` for a number one and `''` for an empty string is better. Just because they are what they are. Not sure where you've read it from, but this whole idea is terrible.

Comment: @zerkms means static string is better than const 
ex. extract(func_get_arg(0)); is better to use 0 directly

Comment: Not even that. The better is to use arguments explicitly: `public function __construct($username, $password)`. A contract must be obvious from the function signature.

Comment: @zerkms yes got your point, this is just an example code, 
i just want to know const is better or static string is better ?

Comment: I think I'm done. I've expressed my opinion 3 times, that should be enough.

Comment: @zerkms if possible add as answer.

Comment: @Raidon, run with the idea. See how you like it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
    Class constantTest{
       const MY_VALUE_TEST='hello Word';
       function constantTest(){
             $startTime=microtime(true);
             $string='';
             for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
                 $string.=self::MY_VALUE_TEST;
             }
             $endTime=microtime(true);
             $totalTime=$endTime-$startTime;
             echo 'Constant = '.$totalTime;
         }
    }
    new constantTest();
    echo "<br>";
    Class StringTest{
         function StringTest(){
            $startTime=microtime(true);
            $string='';
            for($i=0;$i<1000000;$i++){
               $string.='hello Word';
            }
            $endTime=microtime(true);
            $totalTime=$endTime-$startTime;
            echo 'String = '.$totalTime;
        }
   }
   new StringTest();
```

After running this code 3 times ,After comparison with both the style with string and using constant review the execution time as below.

Constant = 0.90771412849426
String = 0.74732899665833

Constant = 0.94015312194824
String = 0.7591450214386

Constant = 0.89980792999268
String = 0.79145216941833

Answer (score 3):

Please refer this link may be it will useful for you to get an answer......

[PHP Constants: Advantages/Disadvantages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247936/php-constants-advantages-disadvantages)

http://amityug.org/wordpress/zimlich/2014/12/28/php-constants-advantagesdisadvantages/

http://imrannazar.com/Memory-Usage-of-Constants-in-PHP